# Using cluster analysis as alternative to point in polygon assignment

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm interested to approach the confirming point in polygon problem from another direction. I have a dataframe containing series of coordinates, known to be in certain polygon (administrative area). I have other dataframes with coordinates not assigned to any admin area. Would using `SciKit` offer an alternate means to assign these to the admin area.

**Example:**

I know `(x, y)` point 1 is in admin area a if `(x, y)` point 2 is within specified radius of point `(1, i)` can assign it to the same admin area. Does this approach sound viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discriminant analisys (a.k.a. supervised  classification) is the way to go. You adjust the model by using the coordinates of the points and the information on the node they belong to. As a result, you obtain a model you can use to predict the node for new points as they are known. Linear discriminant analysis is one of the simplest algorithms.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer. Will return with how that worked and some code for those interested